# How to send changed state to component in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm a beginner of react & react-native.
I'm using react 16, react-thunk, react-redux.

I'm trying to fetch categories that I already made from `firestore`.
At first, I called `action` using `connect()`, and then, I typed `action` using thunk also fetched data from `firestore`.
Finally, I returned new states in reducer.
Definitely, I'm not aware of redux process, so please give some tips.

Here's my code. Thank you.

**CategoryImageList.js (Component)**

```
...

class CategoryImageList extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getCategory();
  }

  renderImages() {
      return this.state.categories.map(category =>
          <CategoryImageCard key={category.imgName} category={category}/>
      );
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <ScrollView>
            {/*{this.renderImages()}*/}
        </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, {getCategory})(CategoryImageList);
```

**category.js (action)**

```js
...
export const getCategory = () => {
  return (dispatch) => { //using redux-thunk here... do check it out
    getCategories()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            const test = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                test.push(
                {
                    imgName : doc.data()['imgName'],
                    name : doc.data()['name']
                });
            });

            dispatch({ type: GET_CATEGORY, payload: test} );
        });
  };
};
```

**CategoryReducers.js (reducer)**

```js
...

const categoryInitialState = {
  name: [],
  imgName: []
}

export const CategoryReducer = (state = categoryInitialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_CATEGORY:
        console.log(action);
        return { ...state, categoryImg: {
            name: action.payload.name,
            imgName: action.payload.imgName
        }};

    default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

**App.js**

```
...
type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
    render() {
        const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
        return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <Header headerText={'FoodUp'}/>
                <CategoryImageList />
            </View>
        </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

**reducers/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { CategoryReducer } from './CategoryReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    categories: CategoryReducer
});
```

**UPDATED**
**Firebase.js**

```
const config = {
  ...
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
const db = firebase.firestore();
const storage = firebase.storage();
const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true};
db.settings(settings);

export const getCategories = () => {
  return db.collection('categories').get();
}

export const getCategoryImg = (categoryName, imgName) => {
  const ref = storage.ref(`category/${categoryName}/${imgName}`);
  return ref.getDownloadURL();
}
```

Comment: Few things, you need to map your store to ur components so that it can access the store data. Then you can use this.props.data in your component to access the store. https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add mapstateToProps to your connect like,

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
  return {
    name: state.categories.name,
    imageName:state.categories.imageName
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CategoryImageList)
```

And then, you will be able to access the name and image name like,
`this.props.name` and `this.props.imageName`

Edit: To dispatch `GET_CATEGORY` you can either use mapDispatchToProps or do the getCategory and dispatch from within your component like,

```
import {getCategory} from './category'

 componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getCategory(this.props.dispatch);
  }
```

and change the getCategory function as,

```
export const getCategory = (dispatch) => {
...
dispatch({ type: GET_CATEGORY, payload: test} );
...
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply.
I guess my action file(category.js) is never called.
So, state is `{imgName:[], name:[]}` because of reducer's initialize.
I have no idea how to call action in `CategoryImageList.js` component.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include answer to ur comment

Comment: Each attributes of the state of `CategoryImageList.js` component is `undefined`. I think it is because `action.payload` is `array`.
In this case, how can I return the state?

Comment: Please post the code of `getCategories()`, coz i guess that is a promise call which never gets called.

Comment: That is in `category.js`.
I think the reason why it returned undefined is that `action.payload` is type of `array`.

Comment: no buddy, in category.js,getCategories() function call is there, I meant the definition of the function is not there in the question you have posted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172372/discussion-between-rohith-murali-and-mingyu-jeon).

Answer (score 0):

mapStateToProps has the Store state as an argument/param (provided by react-redux::connect) and its used to link the component with the certain part of the store state. in your case, you can use like this. and you can use name, imgName as a **props** in your component

```
const mapStateToProps = ({categories}) => {
    const { name, imgName } = categories;
    return {name, imgName};
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getCategory})(CategoryImageList);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I updated my post.
What is MY_STORE_NAME?
I wrote like this,
`createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)`

Comment: @MingyuJeon what is `reducers` in `createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)`? inside that `reducers` file, you can see all your reducer name. if your store is like this there is no STORE_NAME. you have only REDUCER_NAME. can you post `reducers` file also?

Comment: I updated my post.
I have no idea how to call action.
Can be possible to call `action` using `connect(mapStateToProps, {getCategory})(CategoryImage);

`getCategory` is a function in reducer.

Comment: @MingyuJeon I have updated my answer. reducer name was `categories`

Comment: I got this error.
`Invariant Violation: CategoryImageList(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.`

Is this because I return nothing in `render()`?
What should I return then?

Comment: When I logged `action.type` in `CategoryReducer`, I got this, `@@redux/PROBE_UNKNOWN_ACTION_y.m.b.2.b.a`.
It should be `GET_CATEGORY`, but I have no idea why it printed out.
I guess `category.js (action)` is never called.